# Вечное ожидание потока

Tags: python, многопоточность, очередь

Решил попробовать написать код с многопоточностью, но столкнулся с тем, что после выполнения последнего цикла скрипт переходит в вечное ожидание. Как исправить?

```py
    queuelock = threading.Lock()
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    for item in proxyList:
        queue.put(item)
    while not queue.empty():
        queuelock.acquire()
        for i in range(max_threads):
            my_thread = threading.Thread(target=check,args=(queue,))
            my_thread.setDaemon(True)
            my_thread.start()
            threads.append(my_thread)
        for i in threads:
            i.join()
        queuelock.release()
```

```py
def check(q):
    if not q.empty():
        try:
            prox = q.get()
            proxy = {"https":'https://'+prox}
        except: pass
        try:
            r = requests.get(url,proxies=proxy)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                print("%s is good"%prox)
                good.append(prox)
            else:
                print(r.status_code)
                bad.append(prox)
        except Exception as e:
            print('bad proxy %s'%prox)
            bad.append(prox)
    else: pass
```

Comment: Приведите код функции `check`, выполняемой в потоке

Comment: обновил в вопросе

Comment: Попробуйте `my_thread.daemon = True` вместо `my_thread.setDaemon(True)`.  Ваш вариант устарел.

Comment: @V-Mor Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Вынес в ответ. Примите, если больше не осталось вопросов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказано в комментарии к принятому ответу на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5127401/11790859), `my_thread.setDaemon(True)` является устаревшим API и сейчас рекомендуется пользоваться `my_thread.daemon = True` вместо него.

Answer (score 2):

все тоже самое, гораздо короче делать так

```
import multiprocessing.pool

def check(prox):
    r = requests.get(url,proxies={"https":'https://'+prox})
    assert r.status_code == 200
    return r

with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool() as pool:
    for (i, f) in enumerate([pool.apply_async(check, p) for p in proxyList]):
        prox = proxyList[i]
        try:
           r = f.get()
        except Exception as e:
            bad.append(prox)
        else:
            food.append(prox)
```